# Split results in Python for CPU usage

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, raspberry-pi3

Been trying to get this to work for a few hours now.  Nothing I try is splitting this text up.  I only want the Current CPU from this

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> import json
>>> import subprocess
>>> import requests
>>> import random
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> import MySQLdb as my
>>> import psutil
>>> os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
"temp=52.0'C\n"
>>> cpu = psutil.cpu_freq()
>>> cpu = cpu.split('current=')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'scpufreq' object has no attribute 'split'
>>> psutil.cpu_freq()
scpufreq(current=600.0, min=600.0, max=1500.0)
>>> psutil.cpu_freq(percpu=True)
[scpufreq(current=600.0, min=600.0, max=1500.0)]
>>> cpu = psutil.cpu_freq(percpu=True)
>>> cpu.split('=')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
>>> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> psutil.cpu_freq(percpu=True).readline()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readline'
>>> cpu = psutil.cpu_freq()
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

OS: Rasbian Buster
Python: python3
PIP: pip3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks mostly like you're ignoring your error messages:

> ```
> >>> cpu = psutil.cpu_freq()
> >>> cpu = cpu.split('current=')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: 'scpufreq' object has no attribute 'split'
> ```

The return value from `psutil.cpu_freq()` isn't a string, so it doesn't have a `split` method. If you just print the value...

```
>>> cpu
scpufreq(current=700.0, min=700.0, max=800.0)
```

...you get some idea of what attributes it has, and indeed, we can access those values like this:

```
>>> cpu.current
700.0
>>> cpu.max
800.0
```

When you set `percpu=True`, you're getting back a list:

> ```
> >>> psutil.cpu_freq(percpu=True)
> [scpufreq(current=600.0, min=600.0, max=1500.0)]
> ```

And once again, a `list` isn't a string, so there's no `split` method. Since there's only a single CPU, you get back a 1-item list, so you can access values like this:

```
>>> cpu = psutil.cpu_freq(percpu=True)
>>> cpu[0].current
700.0
```

Comment: one more question.  how can i convert this the same way?  Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      4883638268 2688204740 2195433528  56% /media/external

Comment: That's probably worth a second question. If you've got that in a string, you *will* want to use the `split` method.